# Faster Way to Implement Gaussian Smoothing? (Python 3.10, NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I'm attempting to implement a Gaussian smoothing/flattening function in my `Python 3.10` script to flatten a set of XY-points. For each data point, I'm creating a Y buffer and a Gaussian kernel, which I use to flatten each one of the Y-points based on it's neighbours.

Here are some sources on the Gaussian-smoothing method:

- [Source 1](https://towardsdatascience.com/gaussian-smoothing-in-time-series-data-c6801f8a4dc3)
- [Source 2](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/smoothing_intro.html)

I'm using the `NumPy` module for my data arrays, and `MatPlotLib` to plot the data.

I wrote a minimal reproducible example, with some randomly-generated data, and each one of the arguments needed for the Gaussian function listed at the top of the `main` function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def main():
    dataSize = 1000
    yDataRange = [-4, 4]
    reachPercentage = 0.1
    sigma = 10
    phi = 0
    amplitude = 1

    testXData = np.arange(stop = dataSize)
    testYData = np.random.uniform(low = yDataRange[0], high = yDataRange[1], size = dataSize)

    print("Flattening...")
    startTime = time.time()

    flattenedYData = GaussianFlattenData(testXData, testYData, reachPercentage, sigma, phi, amplitude)

    totalTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 2)
    print("Flattened! (" + str(totalTime) + " sec)")

    plt.title(str(totalTime) + " sec")
    plt.plot(testXData, testYData, label = "Original Data")
    plt.plot(testXData, flattenedYData, label = "Flattened Data")
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()

    plt.close()

def GaussianFlattenData(xData, yData, reachPercentage, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    flattenedYData = np.empty(shape = len(xData), dtype = float)

    # For each data point, create a Y buffer and a Gaussian kernel, and flatten it based on it's neighbours
    for i in range(len(xData)):
        gaussianCenter = xData[i]
        baseReachEdges = GetGaussianValueX((GetGaussianValueY(0, 0, sigma, phi, amplitude) * reachPercentage), 0, sigma, phi, amplitude)
        reachEdgeIndices = [FindInArray(xData, GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[0]), xData)), 
                            FindInArray(xData, GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[1]), xData))]
        currDataScanNum = reachEdgeIndices[0] - reachEdgeIndices[1]

        # Creating Y buffer and Gaussian kernel...
        currYPoints = np.empty(shape = currDataScanNum, dtype = float)
        kernel = np.empty(shape = currDataScanNum, dtype = float)

        for j in range(currDataScanNum):
            currYPoints[j] = yData[j + reachEdgeIndices[1]]
            kernel[j] = GetGaussianValueY(j, (i - reachEdgeIndices[1]), sigma, phi, amplitude)

        # Dividing kernel by its sum...
        kernelSum = np.sum(kernel)

        for j in range(len(kernel)):
            kernel[j] = (kernel[j] / kernelSum)

        # Acquiring the current flattened Y point...
        newCurrYPoints = np.empty(shape = len(currYPoints), dtype = float)

        for j in range(len(currYPoints)):
            newCurrYPoints[j] = currYPoints[j] * kernel[j]

        flattenedYData[i] = np.sum(newCurrYPoints)

    return flattenedYData

def GetGaussianValueX(y, mu, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    x = ((sigma * np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(y / (amplitude * np.cos(phi))))) + mu)

    return [x, (mu - (x - mu))]

def GetGaussianValueY(x, mu, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    y = ((amplitude * np.cos(phi)) * np.exp(-np.power(((x - mu) / sigma), 2) / 2))

    return y

def GetClosestNum(base, nums):
    closestIdx = 0
    closestDiff = np.abs(base - nums[0])
    idx = 1

    while (idx < len(nums)):
        currDiff = np.abs(base - nums[idx])

        if (currDiff < closestDiff):
            closestDiff = currDiff
            closestIdx = idx

        idx += 1

    return nums[closestIdx]

def FindInArray(arr, value):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if (arr[i] == value):
            return i

    return -1

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

In the example above, I generate 1,000 random data points, between the ranges of -4 and 4. The `reachPercentage` variable is the percentage of the Gaussian amplitude above which the Gaussian values will be inserted into the kernel. The `sigma`, `phi` and `amplitude` variables are all inputs to the Gaussian function which will actually generate the Gaussians for each Y-data point to be smoothened.

I wrote some additional utility functions which I needed as well.

The script above works to smoothen the generated data, and I get the following plot:

[image]

Blue being the original data, and Orange being the flattened data.

However, it takes a surprisingly long amount of time to smoothen even smaller amounts of data. In the example above I generated 1,000 data points, and it takes ~8 seconds to flatten that. With datasets exceeding 10,000 in number, it can easily take over 10 minutes.

Since this is a very popular and known way of smoothening data, I was wondering why this script ran so slow. I originally had this implemented with standard Pythons `Lists` with calling `append`, however it was extremely slow. I hoped that using the `NumPy` arrays instead without calling the `append` function would make it faster, but that is not really the case.

Is there a way to speed up this process? Is there a Gaussian-smoothing function that already exists out there, that takes in the same arguments, and that could do the job faster?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own version, I'd recommend using the implementation in scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter

Comment: With the `gaussian_filter` in scipy on my machine, on 1000 data points, takes 42 microseconds. With 100000 points it takes 2.65 ms.

Comment: I bet convolution with a Gaussian kernel wouldn't take much longer

Comment: You are trying to take a cross-correlation between your array and a Gaussian.  You can probably accomplish this whole thing in like 2 or 3 loc using [`scipy.signal.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking people on [the Python forums](https://discuss.python.org/t/faster-way-to-implement-gaussian-smoothing-python-3-10-numpy/23058), as well as doing some more searching online, I managed to find much faster alternatives to most of the functions I had in my loop.

In order to get a better image of which parts of the smoothing function took up the most time, I subdivided the code into 4 parts, and timed each one to see how much each part contributed to the total runtime. To my surprise, the part that took up over 90% of the time, was the first part of the loop:

```
        gaussianCenter = xData[i]
        baseReachEdges = GetGaussianValueX((GetGaussianValueY(0, 0, sigma, phi, amplitude) * reachPercentage), 0, sigma, phi, amplitude)
        reachEdgeIndices = [FindInArray(xData, GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[0]), xData)), 
                            FindInArray(xData, GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[1]), xData))]
        currDataScanNum = reachEdgeIndices[0] - reachEdgeIndices[1]
```

Luckly, the people on the Python forums and here were able to assist me, and I was able find a much faster alternative `GetClosestNum` function (thanks Vin), as well as removing the `FindInArray` function:

There are also replacements in the latter parts of the loop, where instead of having 3 `for` loops, they were all replaced my `NumPy` iterative expressions.

The whole script now looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def main():
    dataSize = 3073
    yDataRange = [-4, 4]
    reachPercentage = 0.001
    sigma = 100
    phi = 0
    amplitude = 1

    testXData = np.arange(stop = dataSize)
    testYData = np.random.uniform(low = yDataRange[0], high = yDataRange[1], size = dataSize)

    print("Flattening...")
    startTime = time.time()

    flattenedYData = GaussianFlattenData(testXData, testYData, reachPercentage, sigma, phi, amplitude)

    totalTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 2)
    print("Flattened! (" + str(totalTime) + " sec)")

    plt.title(str(totalTime) + " sec")
    plt.plot(testXData, testYData, label = "Original Data")
    plt.plot(testXData, flattenedYData, label = "Flattened Data")
    plt.legend()

    plt.show()

    plt.close()

def GaussianFlattenData(xData, yData, reachPercentage, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    flattenedYData = np.empty(shape = len(xData), dtype = float)

    # For each data point, create a Y buffer and a Gaussian kernel, and flatten it based on it's neighbours
    for i in range(len(xData)):
        gaussianCenter = xData[i]
        baseReachEdges = GetGaussianValueX((GetGaussianValueY(0, 0, sigma, phi, amplitude) * reachPercentage), 0, sigma, phi, amplitude)
        reachEdgeIndices = [np.where(xData == GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[0]), xData))[0][0], 
                            np.where(xData == GetClosestNum((gaussianCenter + baseReachEdges[1]), xData))[0][0]]
        currDataScanNum = reachEdgeIndices[0] - reachEdgeIndices[1]

        # Creating Y buffer and Gaussian kernel...
        currYPoints = yData[reachEdgeIndices[1] : reachEdgeIndices[1] + currDataScanNum]
        kernel = GetGaussianValueY(np.arange(currDataScanNum), (i - reachEdgeIndices[1]), sigma, phi, amplitude)

        # Acquiring the current flattened Y point...
        flattenedYData[i] = np.sum(currYPoints * (kernel / np.sum(kernel)))

    return flattenedYData

def GetGaussianValueX(y, mu, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    x = ((sigma * np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(y / (amplitude * np.cos(phi))))) + mu)

    return [x, (mu - (x - mu))]

def GetGaussianValueY(x, mu, sigma, phi, amplitude):
    y = ((amplitude * np.cos(phi)) * np.exp(-np.power(((x - mu) / sigma), 2) / 2))

    return y

def GetClosestNum(base, nums):
    nums = np.asarray(nums)

    return nums[(np.abs(nums - base)).argmin()]

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Instead of taking ~8 seconds to process the 1,000 data points, it now takes merely ~0.15 seconds!

[image]

It also takes ~1.75 seconds to process the 10,000 points.

Thanks for the feedback everyone, cheers!

Comment: Please consider not recomputing the Gaussian filter parameters (eg. `GetGaussianValueX`) every time in the loop: this is very inefficient. Besides, please consider using `scipy.signal` as pointed out in the comments since it should be much faster (see for example [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#convolution). The FFT-based version should take a tiny fraction of a second for 10_000 points.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of loops - those tend to slow you down.

Here are two examples. Refactoring `GetClosestNum` to this:

```
def GetClosestNum(base, nums):
    nums = np.array(nums)
    diffs = np.abs(nums - base)
    return nums[np.argmin(diffs)]
```

and refactoring `FindInArray` to this:

```
def FindInArray(arr, value):
    res = np.where(np.array(arr) - value == 0)[0]
    if res.size > 0:
        return res[0]
    else:
        return -1
```

lets me process 5000 datapoints in 1.5s instead of the 54s it took with your original code.

Numpy lets you do a lot of powerful stuff without looping - Jake Vanderplas has a few really good (oldie but goodie) videos on using numpy constructs in place of loops to massively increase speed - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw.